# Uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: boot, software-uninstall

I forgot my passphrase for unlocking my disk. Is there a way to disable it and reset? I've tried using software from a USB drive but won't recognize it. Please help

Comment: So you've protected your actual _disk_ with a password and not just your Ubuntu OS?

Comment: If you enabled full-disk encryption, then the entire point of it is to make accessing the data impossible unless you have the passphrase. (i.e. without the passphrase, your data cannot be decrypted and is, for all practical purposes, gone and irrecoverable.) It is real encryption, not a dinky padlock that can be cut off if you forget the combination. If you're talking about the user login password, you might be in more luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you have full-disk-encryption enabled, there's no way to bypass it. That's *why it exists.*

Your only recourse would be to wipe your drive and try to reinstall Ubuntu.

To erase your drive, open `gparted` on live media and select the disk you installed Ubuntu on. Navigate to **Device** > **Create Partition Table**. If you have a UEFI-aware computer, select `gpt` and confirm. Otherwise, select `msdos`.

Once your drive is cleaned out, you can customize the partitions for it, or just install Ubuntu normally.